# Invoking C++ dll in Blazor client webassembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to invoke C++ DLL in my client webassembly blazor application . However, I am not able to succeed in this.

I am using the following syntax to invoke the dll , however receiving error .

Can anyone help me is Blazor webassembly is supporting invocation of C++ native dll in the client C# code or NO .

I am using the following syntax to call dll from app.

```
   [DllImport("SampleDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

   public static extern int Add(int a, int b);
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: This is not supported. For technical and security reasons, hackers would have a field day.

Comment: How is this any different from javascript calling webassembly libraries? If the C++ native dll is itself compiled to webassemby, I don't see any reason to prevent it.